# Xamarin Android App name not setting

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing Xamarin Android app.
After launching the app on my device, app name is shown as "`$projectname$`" (dollar projectname dollar).
MainActivity (Launch activity)'s label is also shown as "`$projectname$`".

Where comes from `$projectname$` ?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.MyApp.Android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/ic_myapp" android:name=".TSApplication">
        <data android:scheme="com.MyApp.Android" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="ApplicationName">MyApp</string>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
[Activity (Label="@string/ApplicationName")]
public class MainActivity
{
...
}
```

What should I check for fixing this ?

Comment: try write name direct instead of [Activity (Label="@string/ApplicationName")] wrtie [Activity (Label="AppName")]

Comment: if doing it, main activity title is set properly, but app name is never changed. still $projectname$.

Answer (score 4):

to change label of activity just write the label directly

instead of

```
[Activity (Label="@string/ApplicationName")]
```

To

```
[Activity (Label="AppName")]
```

if you still have problem with application name 
check your configuration

[image]

I hope this fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too.

Check out all your projects besides your main project (DataLayer project for example), and see if they have a Strings.xml file. In my case, they all had this file with a `ApplicationName` node in it. The value was, yes, $projectname$...

Xamarin automatically creates these xml files for you when creating a new project, and apparently somehow this string value is used before your main project resources.

For me, deleting all strings.xml files in the projects fixed it.
**Be careful** when deleting these files entirely, if you use them for some other string values, you should just remove the `ApplicationName` xml node from the xml.

This seems to be the problem since a Xamarin.Android update, I know for sure this worked before.

I hope this helps you and others struggling with this problem.

Comment: In my solution, there are iOS, Android, Shared projects, and strings.xml is  exist in Android project only. I included several Components, maybe the problem comes from them?

Comment: I don't it's because of the components. Have you tried searching all files containing "ApplicationName", to be sure it only exists in your main project? You don't have multiple android projects?

Comment: @ttotto, I also hard-coded the application name (`Label="@string/ApplicationName"` to `Label="My application"`). Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

In all of AndroidManifest.xml, MainActivity.cs and Application Properties remove **@string/** where it is and set only your **AppName**.

In other words, set **AppName** insted of **@string/AppName**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do "set AppName instead of @string/AppName." like other answers wrote because "@string/appname" is necessary for localization!

You will need to set "@string/appname" at two places:

1. Xamarin.Android project properties ->Android Manifest -> Application Name.
   This step should set the Properties/AndroidManifest.xml to have this application name:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
```

You may also edit this XML file and change this android:label.

2. MainActivity.cs (or the main Activity you set to)

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ... ]
```

Then you will need to create different strings.xml for your languages under:
Resources\values
Resources\values-zh
Resources\values-jp
...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">Your Application Name</string>
</resources>
```

And one more important step:
Make sure strings.xml are set with the following properties:

- Build Action: AndroidResource
- Custom Tool: MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles